# "Auf Wiederschreiben" als Abschiedsgruß?

Tags: phrase, phrase-request, salutation, letter, writing

Am Ende eines Treffens kann man *Auf Wiedersehen* als Abschiedsgruß benutzen. Am Ende eines Telefongesprächs kann man *Auf Wiederhören* sagen.

Kann man am Ende eines Briefs oder einer E-Mail *Auf Wiederschreiben* benutzen?

Im Duden und de.wiktionary (und Internet im Allgemeinen) konnte ich im Bezug darauf keinen Eintrag finden. Deshalb habe ich das Gefühl, dass das nicht gewöhnlich (oder sogar sinnvoll) ist.

Falls *Auf Wiederschreiben* nicht sinnvoll verwendbar ist, gibt es einen Abschiedsgruß, der zu *Auf Wiedersehen* und *Auf Wiederhören* entspricht, und den man am Ende eines (formellen oder informellen) Schreibens benutzen kann? Zum Beispiel *bis zum nächsten Schreiben*?

Answer (score 3):

Den Ausdruck "Auf Wiederschreiben" gibt es nicht. Deshalb kann man ihn auch nicht als Grußformel in einem Brief verwenden.
Auch "bis zum nächsten Schreiben" klingt sehr ungewöhnlich und wird üblicherweise nicht verwendet.
Ich würde in so einem Fall schreiben: "Ich würde mich freuen, wieder von Ihnen zu hören." oder "Über eine Nachricht von Ihnen würde ich mich sehr freuen."

Comment: Ich kann verwenden, was ich will, und Muttersprachler werden den Begriff verstehen. Kommt natürlich auf den Kontext an, und deshalb würde ich hier nicht "gibt es nicht" sagen.

Comment: @Robert Muttersprachler würden entweder denken "will der mich verarschen?" oder es als Witz auffassen. Im normalen Schriftverkehr gibt es das nicht.

Comment: @äüö Definieren Sie "normalen Schriftverkehr"... Wenn ich einem Kumpel eine Email mit "Auf Wiederschreiben" beende, ist das natürlich etwas anderes als ein Bewerbungsschreiben auf Papier, aber deshalb denkt mein Kumpel noch lange nichts von verarschen. Daher mein Verweis auf den Kontext.

Comment: @Robert: ...tritt Variante b) ein: siehe oben, Kumpel=>"als Witz auffassen"; "normaler Schriftverkehr"=ohne Witz bzw. ohne Verarsche :)

Answer (score 2):

Post ist lästig, und Freunde hört oder trifft man doch lieber anstatt ihnen zu schreiben. Also gibt's auch *Auf Wiederschreiben* nicht. Stattdessen:

> Hochachtungsvoll *(praktisch nur Behördenschreiben)*
>
> Mit freundlichem Gruß / Mit freundlichen Grüßen *(für alle Gelegenheiten)*
>
> Mit herzlichem Gruß / Mit herzlichen Grüßen *(in Dankschreiben)*
>
> Mit liebem Gruß / Mit lieben Grüßen *(Bekannte, Verwandte)*
>
> Bis dann / Bis bald *(enge Freunde)*

Comment: +1. Du könntest noch etwas mit «herzlich» hinzufügen.

Comment: Ich kenne den *herzlichen Gruß* nur aus Dankschreiben. Noch irgendwo?

Comment: «Herzlich, Nachname/Vorname/Kürzel» (je nach Vertrautheit der Korrespondenten) ist bei uns an der Uni der Standard in E-mails zwischen Dozenten und Studenten.